# Strings in mathematical operation in python

Tags: python-3.x

I was having some problems with my code , a statement was giving true when it should've been false

For some reason '6' > '14' was true. I changed them into int s instead of str s and the problem was  solved but i was wondering why this has happened in the first place

here's a picture !(http://prntscr.com/o1c7na)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For comparing strings it compares char by char, the first char `'6'` has a greater ASCII representation that `'1'` hence it is bigger.

Here some examples of the behaviour:

```
>>> "a" > "b"
False
>>> "a" > "aaa"
False
>>> "1" > "2"
False
>>> "12" > "1"
True
>>> "6" > "14"
True
>>> "6" > "1"
True
```

The ASCII code can be retrieve with `ord`:

```
>>> ord("6")
54
>>> ord("1")
49
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the ascii string comparison happens with ascii code comparison of each letter one by one. So in the 1st step 6 is compared to 1 and since 6 is > 1 it returns true.